# Convert an angle in degrees, to a vector

Tags: c#, vector, xna, rotation, degrees

I'm doing some game programming. FWIW I'm using XNA, but I'm doubtful that this is relevant.

I'd like to convert degrees to a directional vector (ie X and Y) with magnitude 1.

My origin (0,0) is in the upper left.

So I'd like 0 degrees to convert to [0, -1]

I thought the best way to do this was to take my definition of North/Up and rotate it using a matrix, but this does not seem to be working.

**Here is the Code...**

```
public class Conversion
{
    public static Vector2 GetDirectionVectorFromDegrees(float Degrees)
    {
        Vector2 North= new Vector2(0, -1);
        float Radians = MathHelper.ToRadians(Degrees);

        var RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Radians);
        return Vector2.Transform(North, RotationMatrix);
    }
}
```

**... and here are my unit tests...**

```
[TestFixture]
public class Turning_Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Degrees0_Tests()
    {
        Vector2 result = Conversion.GetDirectionVectorFromDegrees(0);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result.X);
        Assert.AreEqual(-1, result.Y);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Degrees90_Tests()
    {
        Vector2 result = Conversion.GetDirectionVectorFromDegrees(90);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.X);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Y);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Degrees180_Tests()
    {
        Vector2 result = Conversion.GetDirectionVectorFromDegrees(180);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result.X);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Y);
    }
    [Test]
    public void Degrees270_Tests()
    {
        Vector2 result = Conversion.GetDirectionVectorFromDegrees(270);
        Assert.AreEqual(-1, result.X);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Y);
    }

}
```

Am I approaching this all wrong?
Should I be using a matrix?
Have I screwed up and converted from degrees to radians in the wrong place?

I've seen suggestions that this can be done using code like:

```
new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(Angle), (float)Math.Sin(Angle));
```

...or sometimes...

```
new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(Angle), (float)Math.Cos(Angle));
```

However these don't seem to work either

**Can someone put me on the right path... or better yet give me some code which causes the 4 provided unit tests to path?**

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use:

```
new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(radians), (float)Math.Sin(radians))
```

Be sure to convert from degrees to radians with this approach too.

This uses the mathematician's convention of starting from `[1, 0]` and going in the direction towards `[0, 1]` (that is counter-clockwise with the orientation that mathematicians use for the two axes).

To use instead your convention (starting from `[0, -1]` and going in the direction of `[1, 0]`) you need:

```
new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(radians), -(float)Math.Cos(radians))
```

Note that your conversion from degrees to radians can never be exact (it involves something with `π`). You should allow for some tolerance in your tests. Also, if you use `double` instead of `float` for the `radians`, you will have some extra precision in the intermediate calculation.

Comment: @RoryBecker See my edit. When working with `Sin` and `Cos` you cannot expect exact values. The values must be very close to the expected value, though.

Comment: When I saw my unit tests failing, I assumed that this was bad. As you point out however, this is down to rounding errors, which as it turns out are well within a usable tolerance. Thank you so much :)

Comment: There are really eight different possible "conventions" for _(a)_ which "corner" (intersection between an axis and the unit circle) to start from (4 possibilities) and _(b)_ which direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise) to use (2 possibilities). That corresponds to the eight possibilities of choosing _(i)_ order of `Cos` and `Sin` (that is `Cos` first (x), then `Sin` (y), or vice versa), _(ii)_ sign (minus or not) on the first coordinate, and _(iii)_ sign on the last coordinate.

Comment: FWIW I have upgraded my copy of NUnit and now call new overloads of AreEqual which can take tolerances. In this case I have allowed for tolerances of 0.00001. This appears more than adequate. Thanks once again @Jeppe for your help :)