# Getting the correct movement vector to fire a bullet from a rotated sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

[image]

Hi,

I'm using a SKNode to represent a ship sprite. This sprite can be rotated and moved by touch events. This sprite should fire a bullet (another SKNode object) every second.

I plan to use SKAction to move the bullet.

The zRotation method of SKNode objects returns the rotation around the z-Axis. But how can I transform this into the right vector?

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Comment: Isn't the centre point of the object and the angle of rotation to determine the vector at which the bullets need to be fired?

Comment: ie like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851761/convert-an-angle-in-degrees-to-a-vector

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for the link. That's the solution to my problem.

Comment: @rakeshbs Yes. My issue was that I didn't know how to calculate this vector. Thanks for your help